# Image header on android studio navigation drawer not fitting properly

Tags: android, header, navigation, drawer

I have created an android app with a navigation bar activity. I have added an image header to the navigation drawer activity. But, it is showing a little gap in the left. 
Please help me. 
Here is the link to the emulator screenshot.
https://drive.google.com/uc?export=download&id=0ByJqiordkH5zYm9mam1MTTRvU2c
Thanks.

Also, send me a good tutorial on adding icons to items in navigation drawer.

Comment: how much width you are applying to image header??

Comment: 300dp. Match parent is not working either

Answer (score 0):

Thanks I did it. I used android:ScaleType="fitStart" to clear this.